# Use "greater than or equals" or just "greater than"

Tags: c#, .net, c

I remember from C days that we were encouraged to use

```
i > -1
```

instead of

```
i >= 0
```

because of performance.

Does this still apply in the C# .NET world? What are the performance implications of using one over the other with today's compilers? i.e. Is the compiler clever enough to optimize these for you?

(As an aside try and type the question "use >= or >" into the question field on Stack Overflow and see what happens.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, there are no performance issues associated with comparison operators.  And any good compiler would optimize something this trivial anyway.

I'm not sure where you got the suggestion to use "i > -1" rather than "i >= 0".  On the x86 architecture, it makes no difference which you use: either case takes exactly two instructions... one to compare and one to jump:

```
 ;; if (i > -1) {
 cmp eax, -1
 jle else
then:
 ...
else:

 ;; if (i >= 0) {
 cmp eax, 0
 jl else
then:
 ...
else:
```

On most RISC architectures that I know, "i >= 0" may actually be faster since there is usually a dedicated zero register, and "i > -1" may require loading a constant.  For example, MIPS only has a < instruction (no <=).  Here is how the two constructs would be (naively!) expressed in MIPS assembly language:

```
 // if (i >= 0) {   (assuming i is in register %t0)

 stl $t1, $0, $t0     // in C: t1 = (0 < t0)
 beq $t1, $0, else    // jump if t1 == 0, that is if t0 >= 0
 nop
then:
 ...
else:

// if (i > -1) {    (assuming i is in register %t0)

 addi $t2, $0, -1      // in C: t2 = -1
 stl $t1, $t2, $t0      // in C: t1 = (t2 < t0) = (-1 < t0)
 bne $t1, $0, else     // jump if t1 != 0, that is if t0 > -1
 nop
then:
 ...
else:
```

So in the naive, general case, it will actually be one instruction faster to do "i >= 0" on MIPS.  Of course, RISC code is so heavily optimizable that a compiler would likely change either of these instruction sequences almost beyond recognition :-)

So... the short answer is no no no, no difference.

Comment: `(no no no, no difference) = !(!(!(!difference))) = !(!difference)) = difference` ;)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, hard to argue with that. Now I'm kind of tempted to add a 5th "no" :-P

Answer (score 12):

Quite apart from the fact that any decent compiler does the right thing, and apart from that fact that in modern architectures there's no speed difference between `>` and `>=` comparisons, the bigger picture says that this is a "micro-optimisation" that doesn't affect runtime performance in the vast majority of cases.

In the case of comparisons it usually doesn't affect readability whichever way you write it, but there are occasions when picking one boundary over the other is clearer: e.g.,

```
if (length >= str.size())
```

versus

```
if (length > str.size() - 1)
```

I don't know about you, but I'd pick option 1 any day. :-) In cases that don't appreciably affect performance, such as this, the more readable option should win.

Comment: Right on.  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  (Donald Knuth)

Comment: Note that if str.size() returns an unsigned quantity, the two statements above are not equivalent.  In particular, the latter statement will never evaluate true if str.size() is zero.  I have at times made use of such code, though I generally add an explicit typecast to unsigned: if the sizes are 'short', "if (length > (unsigned short)(str.size-1))" would help make clear that the code would expect wrapping behavior.

Answer (score 9):

There is a very similar question (no criticism implied - as you say, searching for symbols is tricky) here: ["Should one use `<` or `<=` in a for loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182600/should-one-use-or-in-a-for-loop#182620)

(Yes, I happen to be able to find it easily as I've got a lot of upvotes on my answer...)

Basically, do whatever's most readable. The day someone correctly guesses that making a change away from the most readable form is going to solve a performance problem (without the help of a profiler) is the day I stop talking about performance :)

Answer (score 5):

No you don't need to do this any more. Yes the compilers have become much smarter and the two expressions have no performance differences.

Comment: I still can't believe that there ever was an environment where it *would* make a difference.  Can anyone tell me of an extant architecture where one requires fewer cycles than the other???

Comment: Sounds like a programming urban legend

Answer (score 3):

> I remember from C days that we were encouraged to use  .... because of performance.

Are you *sure* about that?  I've worked with computers going back to the early '70's (yes, at my father's knee...), and I've never seen a CPU that couldn't process >= just as fast as >.  (BH  "Branch High" vs. BNL "Branch Not Low" in IBM360 talk).

Comment: I agree, James.  The one I can think of is MIPS, which only has less-than.  So the compiler usually rearranges "a <= b" to "not (b < a)".  The only case where that doesn't work is when one is a NON-ZERO constant...

Comment: I think that's a common myth. I've heard it from co-workers and seen it on the internet a few times even in the last few years. Even without the compiler optimizing away the difference, that's a huge waste of effort to save one cpu instruction.

Comment: As you say - it was probably something that I was misinformed about - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

That might have been true for some shady scripting languages that break down a >= into 2 comparisons, but whoever encouraged you to use that for C... well... you should probably try hard to forget everything they ever told you.

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of the recommendation to use ++i instead of i++ (pre-increment vs. post-increment) because it was *supposedly* one instruction faster. (I forget where I originally read about this, but it was probably C/C++ Users' Journal or Dr. Dobb's Journal but I can't seem to find a web reference.)

I seriously doubt that > or >= is faster or slower; instead write your code for clarity.

As a side note, I developed a preference for the pre-increment (++i) operator even if the reason is now potentially outdated.

Comment: In C++, there are reasons to prefer one increment over the other - I believe it is the pre-increment that is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

For greater than zero, it must make two checks. It checks if the negative bit is off and it checks if the zero bit is off.

For greater than or equal to zero, it only has to check if the negative bit is off, because we don't care if the zero bit is on or off.