# Performance of "enhanced" for loop vs "traditional" for loop?

Tags: java

Java 5 brought about the additions of "enhanced" for loops, providing better syntax that was more concise, and less prone to errors or syntactical bugs by programmers. In addition, it seems to be easier to use.

However, I've heard there are performance enhancements with the "enhanced" for loop as well. Is this true, and if so, what are the performance differences between the two styles of looping?

Comment: You might like to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093537/for-loop-optimization/)

Comment: Thanks jigar for letting this know