# Best Practice in `For` loop in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [for loop optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093537/for-loop-optimization)

In java i have a block of code:

```
List e = {element1, element2, ...., elementn};
for(int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++){//Do something in here
};
```

and another block:

```
List e = {element1, element2, ...., elementn};
int listSize = e.size();
for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){//Do something in here
};
```

I think that the second block is better, because in the first block, if `i++`, we have to calculate `e.size()` one more times to compare the condition in the `for` loop. Is it right or wrong?
And comparing the two block above, what is the best practice for writing for? And why?Explain clearly and try this loop yourself

Comment: The second one because you don't calculate list size in every iteration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally I'd use the enhanced for statement instead:

```
for (Object element : e) {
    // Use element
}
```

Unless you *need* the index, of course.

If I *had* to use one of the two forms, I'd use the first as it's tidier (it doesn't introduce another local variable which is only used in that loop), until I had concrete evidence that it was causing a problem. (In most list implementations, `e.size()` is a simple variable access which can be inlined by the JIT anyway.)

Comment: [http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html) As i read in the link before, the second block is better than the first one! :(

Comment: @Kingfisher: That's *specifically* for Android, where the JIT was more primitive, although I wouldn't be surprised to hear that it copes with this situation now anyway. But in general, *don't micro-optimize without evidence*.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, the most brief and readable code is the best choice, all things being equal. In the case of Java, the enhanced for loop (which works with any class that implements `Iterable`) is the way to go.

```
for (Object object : someCollection) { // do something }
```

In terms solely of the two you posted, I think the first is the better option. It's more readable, and you have to remember that, under the hood, JIT will attempt to optimize a great deal of the code you write anyway.

**EDIT**: Have you heard the phrase "premature optimisation is the root of all evil"? Your second block is an example of premature optimisation.

Comment: As Jon Skeet suggests, if for some reason you need the index into the collection you are iterating over, take use the first form of the loop.

Comment: +1 achievable and comprehensive

Comment: [_Link Here_](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html)  As i read in the link here, the second block is better than the first one!

Comment: @Kingfisher that is interesting. But at the start of the document it does say this: "This document is about Android-specific micro-optimization, so it assumes that you've already used profiling to work out exactly what code needs to be optimized"

Answer (score 5):

I would always use (if you need an index variable):

```java
List e = {element1, element2, ...., elementn};
for(int i = 0, size = e.size(); i < size; i++){
    // Do something in here
};
```

Since `e.size()` could be an expensive operation.

Your 2nd option is not good, since it introduces a new variable outside of the `for` loop. I recommend to keep variable visibility as limited as possible.

Otherwise a

```java
for (MyClass myObj : list) {
    // Do something here
}
```

is even cleaner, but might introduce a small performance hit (the index approach doesn't require to instantiate an `Iterator`).

Comment: +1 for the initalisation of a size  variable in the for loop, I think it's pretty elegant (although I don't believe in micro-optimisation, unless it's REALLY necessary). Anyway, good snippet :)

Comment: -1 e.size() it's NOT an expensive operation, why would it be!?
if you decompile implementation of e.size() method you will see that's just return size variable, and that's not "expensive" operation.

Comment: @AndreaBori that's just an example. Of course it is not an expensive operation for a simple `List`. But it is best practice to not use a method call in the condition part of a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

If you check the size() implementation on a `LinkedList` class, you will find that the size is incemented or decremented when an element is added or removed from the list. 
Calling `size()` just returns the value of this property and does not involve any calculation.

So directly calling size() method should be better as you will save on the save for another integer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the second form is marginally more efficient as you don't repeated perform the `size()` method invocation.  Compilers are good are doing this sort of optimisation themselves.

**However, it's unlikely that this would be the performance bottleneck of your application.  [Avoid premature optimisation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)**.  Make your code clean and readable foremost.

Answer (score 1):

Second one is better approach because in the first block, you are calling the `e.size()` is a method which is an operation in a loop  that is a extra burden to JVM.

Comment: Best practice suggests writing the most *readable* code first, rather than micro-optimizing...

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet. But in many places it is often misread or misunderstood.I also thought that best practices means, writing code that will be too lite for JVM to execute.

Answer (score 1):

HotSpot will move e.size() from cycle in most cases. So it will calculate size of List only once.

As for me I prefer the following notation:

```
for (Object elem: e) {
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this should be much more better..
may be initializing the int variable every time can be escaped from this..

```
List e = {element1, element2, ...., elementn};
int listSize = e.size();
int i=0;
for(i = 0; i < listSize; i++){//Do something in here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not so sure but i think the optimizer of java will replace the value with a static value, so in the end it will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all this numbering and iterators and checkings in writing the code use the following simple most readable code that has its performance to maximum.
Why this has maximum performance (details are coming up)

```
for (Object object : aCollection) { 
// Do something here
}
```

If the index is needed then:
To choose between the above two forms:
The second is the better as you said because it only calculated the size once.

Answer (score 0):

I think now we have a tendency to write short and understandable code, so the first option is better.

Answer (score -1):

the second is better , cos in the firt loop in the body of it maybe u will do this statment
e.remove, and then the size of e will be changed , so it is better to save the size in a parameter before the looop

Comment: Wouldn't that throw a ConcurrentModificationException (or something like that)?

Comment: no , it will no throw any exception if u remove an element of a list inside a loog , just u will get an element without scaning

Comment: If you remove an item from the list, the size will indeed be changed - so your loop boundary is then broken. Sounds like an argument for the first form to me (although you'd *also* have to decrement `i` to avoid skipping an element).

Comment: I guess it will actually just throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException if you don't adjust the variable used to keep track of the list size.

Comment: no it will not , cos the size of the list in ur first cas calcualte dynamicly for every value of i , it is not static

Comment: I'm talking about the Exception getting thrown with Option 2 (since that's what was suggested by this answer). If you use option 2 and remove an element from the list, you will get an Exception if you attempt to access every element.