# Does a for-each loop differ from a regular for loop in the way it iterates through lists?

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Consider an `ArrayList<String> list` for the following examples.

I'm curious about how a for-each loop works "behind the scenes".  A traditional for loop accesses elements of a list by their numerical index, like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
```

Does the for-each syntax access the elements of the list in an essentially different way?  Or is it just a shorthand version for the same thing?

For example, in the following loop, is there implicitly a variable created (like `i` above)?  If there is, does it have a name?  If not, are the elements of the list still accessed sequentially?

```
for(String item : list)
```

Comment: It uses a standard Iterator.  It doesn't know that iterating a List could be done with a get().  It only uses an index lookup for arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enhanced for loop is implemented as a basic for loop using iterators.

See [JLS - Section # 14.14](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14):

> The meaning of the enhanced for statement is given by translation into
>   a basic for statement, as follows:
>
> - If the type of Expression is a subtype of `Iterable`, then the translation is as follows.
>
>   If the type of Expression is a subtype of `Iterable<X>` for some type argument X, then let I be the type `java.util.Iterator<X>`;
>     otherwise, let I be the raw type `java.util.Iterator`.
>
> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
>         (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It uses `iterator` behind the scene, not the traditional index

```
for(String name: names){
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (Iterator<String> i = names.iterator(); i.hasNext();){

}
```

**Also See**

- [for loop optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093537/for-loop-optimization/6093556#6093556)

Answer (score 1):

The enhanced for-loop is shot-hand for iterator based access to a list, not index based.  It works like this:

```
Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
  String item = itr.next():
  //your code
}
```