# Is it more efficient to declare a variable inside a loop, or just to reassign it?

Tags: java, performance, loops, initialization, declaration

While writing loops I often get confused with which one I should choose. For example,

```
int sum;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   sum=0;
   ...
   ....
}
```

Or

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   int sum=0;
   ...
   ....
}
```

Say, the variable is only required in this loop. There is no need of it in the later part of the program. I need the value of the variable sum to be 0 at the beginning of the loop.
Which one is the better practice? Re-initializing a variable at the start of the loop or re-declaring it? Which one is more efficient?

Comment: Thinking about it in terms of how I would convert that into assembly, they should be the same. But that's not to say the JVM will never do something stupid that messes it up and makes one of them less efficient.

Comment: @KhairulBasar: Both are not equal.

Comment: They have the *same* "efficiency" - declarations are *not* "executed" by the JVM and so do not incur any overhead as envisioned; the scope of `sum` is irrelevant to this discussion, being a local variable in either case, as the usage is not shown to be required later. (Although I encourage using the most restrictive scope possible.)

Comment: Please learn about `scope` of a variable.

Comment: The compiler will move your declaration inside the loop if you don't use the variable past the loop, so from a performance perspective, they are exactly the same.

Comment: Basically - don't worry about it.  If there is a difference (and there probably isn't), it's going to be tiny.  You've got better ways of spending your time.

Comment: @1336087: i meant both are equal in efficiency...

Comment: Why don't you just run both versions and measure their execution time?

Comment: @user2040251 because that's harder than it sounds. You have to fight the optimizer to get useful info.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8878071) answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring variables inside or outside of a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you declare a variable outside of the loop and not use it past the loop, the compiler will move the declaration inside the loop.

That means there is no reason to compare efficiency here, since you end up with the same exact code that the JVM will run for the two approaches.

So the following code:

```
int sum;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   sum=0;
}
```

... becomes this after compilation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;
}
```

Comment: is there any differences between them in efficiency ?

Comment: Technically, a declaration isn't executed so the compiler doesn't/can't move it, but you're basically correct.

Answer (score 1):

This leads us to concentrate on `performance and optimization` of code in looping concepts.

From a maintenance perspective, second case is better. Declare and initialize variables in the same place, in the `narrowest scope` possible. Don't leave a gaping hole between the `declaration` and the `initialization`.The scope of local variables should always be the smallest possible.See the link

[Declaring variables inside or outside of a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803674/declaring-variables-inside-or-outside-of-a-loop)

Comment: @anirban.at.web see this also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093537/for-loop-optimization

Answer (score 0):

Re initializing it within the loop will set the sum value to zero every time you start the loop, no need to re-declare.  The answer is both have same efficiency.

Comment: it's not the correct answer to his question- "which one is more efficient ?"

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry then. Then the answer is both have same efficiency.