# Loop and comparison optimization

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I have the following code:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++)
        count.add(0);

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    { 
        for(int j=0;j<l.size();j++)
        {
            if(list.get(i).equals(l.get(j)))
            {
                int val = count.get(j);
                count.set(j, val+1);
            }   
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when running the two for loops and comparison, it takes an extremely long time to run, since the loops I am iterating through have:

```
size > 150000, also both "list" and "l" are ArrayLists
```

Is there any way to optimize this so that the time taken to run the program decreases?

I have looked at this:  [for loop optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093537/for-loop-optimization) and many more pages however the solutions don't help in my instance.

---------UPDATE----------

The comparison is for integer value, this if "list" contains the number 8 four times and "l" contains the number 8, the counter should increment to 4.

Similar to what a Hash Map does, however I personally do not like Hash Maps which is why I am not using them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you might want to include an explenation what this loop is supposed to do. Also include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with input and output.

Comment: it looks like a naive occurrence counter. Cosider using `Map<MyClass, Integer>` for `count` instead of `List<Integer>`

Comment: The nested loops will finally iterate 150000 x 150000 times if I do understand well. No wonder that it can take some time. Do you have any idea of how it would take?

Comment: @KevinEsche its meant to increment the counter variable if the elements in both arraylists match

Comment: @C.Champagne its take a few minutes, that is why im asking what I can do in order to speed up the process, even if it is changing the loops into something else

Comment: @KyhleOhlinger so if both `List` do contain the number `2` twice, the correct count result should be `4`?

Comment: @KyhleOhlinger please update your question so we could exactly understand what you need--I bet there nice and effective O(N) solution for whatever you're trying to implement. Now your intention is not clear. Examples will help.

Comment: The question has been updated

Comment: I don't get why don't you like `HashMap`s? They have specific purpose and could be very useful in cases like yours.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov I am attempting to better a portion of someone elses code which is >1 million lines, in which they have used the results obtained from the for loops above, the loops are the only parts which are slowing the process down and as such I don't want to have to modify all the resulting code as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, you're trying to count how many times the elements from `list` appear in `l`.

And currently you've implemented a fairly naive solution that's of complexity `O(n * m)` (assuming that `list` has `n` elements and `l` has `m` elements).

In order to improve the performance, you need to improve the time complexity of your solution. You could create a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` that will hold how many times a number is appearing in `l` and then use it while iterating through the elements of `list`.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer i : l) {
    map.put(i, map.getOrDefault(i, 0) + 1);
}
```

Then, for each element of `list`, you just need to check how many times its value appears in `l`. Again, I'll use a `Map`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
for (Integer value : list) {
    Integer temp = count.get(value);
    if (temp != null) {
        count.put(value, temp + 1);
    } else {
        count.put(value, map.getOrDefault(value, 0) + 1);
    }
}
```

Since querying a `HashMap` takes a constant time (`O(1)`), then this solution will work with a `O(n + m)` complexity, which is far much better from `O(n * m)`.

However, since you didn't explain what exactly you're problem is, nor what is the content of the lists, I cannot guarantee that these snippets are *exactly* what you need, but you should be able to adjust this approach to your problem.

Comment: you're the King of refactoring )

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is what OP wants, but if he wants to check how many times elements from `list` appear in `l` wont this create wrong results (as for count == 1) for non existing values?. (If that´s what he wants)

Comment: @KevinEsche, you're right. I supposed that if a number `x` appears in any of the lists, it should be counted once. But like I said, I cannot guarantee this is exactly what the OP needs, but they should be able to easily adjust this approach to their problem. :)

Comment: It could happen than, for two different integer values, the hash function give the same position.  It could be better to put an array.

Comment: @JoseLuis, yup you're right. But in this case we need to know the maximal value in the lists, because we need to know the size of the array. :) And if it's something like `10^18`, then our solution will be of `O(10^18)` (because of the array initialization), which is not better than the naive `O(n * m)` approach. :)

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov Thank you, I have managed to edit your solution and store the resulting Key Value Pairs into another ArrayList, which has sped up the time tremendously